# How to seperate a python file to couple files, making a real game with files

Tags: python, pygame

I made a little game with python/pygame. It's in one folder and it's 300+ lines. I want to develop this little game. I'm seeing lots of  games
made by pygame, and I'm seeing they have folders like `main.py` , `classes.py` and `setup.py`.

But I only know the python language and a little pygame. How can I do the file things, or how can I learn?

Comment: Have you read anything about how python modules and imports work? Take a look here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html, specifically at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages. Happy learning!

Comment: Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import a file called *script.py* from the same directory as your main file:

```
import script
```

To import a file called *script.py* from a sub directory called *app*:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert('app')
import script
```

To import a file called *script.py* from the parent directory:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))
import script
```

To import a file called *script.py* from a sibling directory called *app*:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../app'))
import script
```

The methods described above are fine if you need to quickly import a few files, but it is commonly recommended that people use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) when handling larger projects.

Comment: Thanks! I look at virtualenv.